# installing pytorch to one conda evnironment removes existing installation from other conda environments

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, conda

The `pip` was installed per each environment and `which pip` returns proper(and different) location for different conda environments.
I am not using any external scripts for the installation. It's vanilla `pip install` and also tried `python -m pip install`. Also tried to install with conda. In all of these cases, installing it for env1 will uninstall it from env2 and vice versa. No matter from which env I am installing, all envs will use the same version that was installed last.

Not sure if it's relevant, but I am using WSL2.

What could go wrong? What else should I check?

Comment: Never encountered this before. Maybe check if there are any global- or user-level configuration settings (there shouldn't be), i.e., `pip config list --user` (or `--global`). Are the Python versions identical across environments? The question would be much improved by documenting exact reproduce steps, including environment creation, package installation, how you verify installation, etc..

Comment: There is no --user nor --global configs. I don't think I can write a simple reproduction example. Most probably, there is something with my system. So, it's more like a question on how to investigate something like this?

Comment: Not sure. I'd check the `site-packages` directories of the envs to verify package installation. Also, check the `import sys; print(sys.path)` in the Python interpreters to see where they load from. Is PYTHONPATH set anywhere? Are there any user-level packages installed (check `~/.local/lib/python*/site-packages/`)? Do you have the issue using a Conda build of Pytorch? e.g., `conda install -c pytorch pytorch`

Comment: PYTHONPATH is not set. I didn't install it per user. Had this issue with both, conda and pip.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea what is causing this behavior but at least found a workaround - using pip `--ignore-installed` option:

```
conda activate your_target_env
pip install --ignore-installed torch torchvision torchaudio
```

This will not uninstall other versions of pytorch installed inside other conda environments. And both environments will work with their versions of pytorch.